# Why can’t I upvote a comment more than once?

Tags: support, comments, voting

Realizing my mistake of upvoting a comment on a question, I clicked the upvote arrow again to undo it. At my surprise, I received a pop-up alert saying that if I undo this upvote I won’t be able to upvote the comment again. I accepted, and to test this, I attempted to upvote it again, which was unsuccessful as expected.

Why can’t users be given a second chance to upvote comments?

I [searched for similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=upvote+comment+twice), but they only seem to cover mobile app crashes. Is that the sole reasoning?

Comment: comment votes dont change rep, so its no so important to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to promote paying due attention when you vote i.e. your vote (even on comments) is has some value so use it wisely.

Comment: That is possible, but then I would ask why this limitation isn't enforced for questions and answers, whose votes definitely have a greater effect. If your message is, "your vote is important so use it wisely," then I would think that question/answer votes would be treated even more strictly than comment votes.

Comment: @chharvey You can only change your vote on a question or answer after it has been edited, and a question or answer can be edited in perpetuity.  On the other hand, except for moderators, comments can only be edited for 5 minutes which locks in their content.

Comment: @PolyGeo You can actually change your vote as much as you want as long as you don't wait more than 5 minutes between vote changes. With comments, you only get one upvote and one un-upvote no matter what.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I think the principle still applies that the more locked in the content is, the less desirable it is for votes to be alterable on a whim.

Comment: That would be such a silly reason. Why not be consistent and promote "paying due attention" everywhere then? Why only this specific bit? By the same logic, why not limit viewing each question to one time, asking a question to one time per account, logging in to once a day, querying a search result to once per lifetime, disallow editing? Cuz you know, should've given more thought and paid more attention the first time around. Hey why not only support scrolling down? You don't need to scroll up, just pay attention the first time around.

Comment: @gargoylebident because all of those things would hinder usage of the site. Limiting voting on things to within a reasonable time-span (or to just once, in the case of comments) does not.